# Banknote change maker in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, coin-change

I've been studying Haskell and I successfully make an algorithm to decompose a given monetary value in the banknotes it would take to sum this value. A better explanation (and the challenge itself) can be found [here](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1018).

```
import Text.Printf
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

filterNearest :: Int->(Int->Bool)
filterNearest a = (\x -> (max a x) <= a)

findNearest :: Int->[Int]->Int
findNearest x possibilities = last $filter (filterNearest x) possibilities

decomposeOnce :: Int->[Int]->[Int]->[Int]
decomposeOnce x list possibilities = [findNearest x possibilities] ++ list

decomposeRecursive :: Int->[Int]->[Int]->[Int]
decomposeRecursive x list possibilities = if x /= 0
    then
        let decomposed = decomposeOnce x list possibilities
        in decomposeRecursive (x - decomposed!!0) decomposed possibilities
    else list

countGroup :: [Int]->(Int, Int)
countGroup list = (list!!0, length list)

makeGroups :: [Int]->[(Int, Int)]
makeGroups list = map countGroup $group list

hasGap :: [(Int, Int)]->(Int->Bool)
hasGap dta = (\idx -> not $any (==idx) $map fst dta)

findGaps :: [(Int, Int)]->[Int]->[Int]
findGaps dta required = filter (hasGap dta) required

fillGaps :: [(Int, Int)]->[Int]->[(Int, Int)]
fillGaps dta gaps = dta ++ map (\x -> (x, 0)) gaps

sortData :: [(Int, Int)]->[(Int, Int)]
sortData dta = reverse $sortBy (comparing fst) dta

calc :: Int->[(Int, Int)]
calc x = let dta = makeGroups $decomposeRecursive x [] [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100]
         in sortData $fillGaps dta $findGaps dta [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100]

formatData :: (Int, Int)->String
formatData dta = (show $snd dta) ++ " nota(s) de R$ " ++ (show $fst dta) ++ ",00\n"

main = do
    x <- readLn
    print x
    printf $intercalate "" $map formatData $calc x
```

There is cases that I think I could have used the function composition operator, but I couldn't manage to apply it properly, so I'd like to ask for help for applying function composition is some spots:

```
findNearest :: Int->[Int]->Int
findNearest x possibilities = last $filter (filterNearest x) possibilities
```

Why can't I do `last.filter (filterNearest x) possibilities`?

```
sortData :: [(Int, Int)]->[(Int, Int)]
sortData dta = reverse $sortBy (comparing fst) dta
```

Why can't I do `reverse.sortBy comparing.fst dta`?

Am I getting the concept wrong?

Comment: http://pointfree.io/ can help with this sometimes. In this case it will give you `sortData = reverse . sortBy (comparing fst)` which is a bit nicer. This is an example of eta-reduction, which is the rule that if your function ends by applying an argument, you can instead omit the argument and write your body as a composition of functions.

Comment: The brackets are wrong, it should be `sortData = reverse . sortBy (comparing fst)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function composition `.` is not the same thing as function application `$`. You can't swap out `$` for `.` and expect the program to have the same meaning. They're different things.

**First, function application**. It is defined like this:

```
f $ x = f x
```

The operator takes a function on the left side and a value on the right side, and merely passes the value to the function as an argument. Take, for example, your expression:

```
last $ filter (filterNearest x) possibilities
```

Compare with definition of the operator `$`: in your code `f` is `last` and `x` is `filter (filterNearest x) possibilities`. Therefore, your code is equivalent to this:

```
last (filter (filterNearest x) possibilities)
```

**Now, let's look at function composition**. It is defined like this:

```
f . g = \y -> f (g y)
```

This means that the result of composing two functions `f` and `g` is *another function*, which passes its argument to `g` and then passes `g`'s return value to `f`.

Now take a look at your attempted code:

```
last . filter (filterNearest x) possibilities
```

Compare with the definition: `f` is `last` and `g` is `filter (filterNearest x) possibilities`. The imporant thing to note here is that the second argument `filter (filterNearest x) possibilities` is *not a function*! So no wonder it cannot be composed via function composition.

But your intuition is, in fact, correct (or is it your homework assignment?): function composition can indeed be used in this context and provide some benefit.

Let's take a look at this expression:

```
last . filter (filterNearest x)
```

Compare with the definition: `f` is `last` and `g` is `filter (filterNearest x)`. Now both arguments are, in fact, functions, and therefore, function composition can be applied. To see the result of applying it, just use substitution:

```
   last . filter (filterNearest x)
== \y -> last (filter (filterNearest x) y)
```

So the result of such composition is a function that takes a list as a parameter, filters that list, and then takes the last element of the result. So the full definition of `findNearest` could look like this:

```
findNearest :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
findNearest x = last . filter (filterNearest x)
```

See what the function composition saved you? Now you don't have to write out the second parameter! Most Haskell programmers would consider this a benefit, but I also know some people who would frown at this, arguing that this made the program less understandable. To each their own, but useful to note this disagreement.

I'll leave similar transformation of `sortData` as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, things are much more clear now. I made the ``sortData = reverse.sortBy (comparing fst)`` (it was exactly the same as the previous function, so not big deal).

It's not a homework assignment tho, I'm learning "by myself"

Answer (score 0):

Even though you specifically asked about function composition, I'd like to remark that most of your code is equivalent to the three-liner:

```
decompose = f [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]
  where f (coin:coins) value = (value `div` coin) : f coins (value `rem` coin)
        f [] _ = []
```

The way you approached the problem is way too complicated. Instead, start with the largest coin, calculate how often it fits and how much remains, then repeat with the second largest coin and so on.

Comment: this code is wrong btw. even when its obvious errors are fixed, depending on the list of available denominations, this unconditional approach might overshoot the target and result in failure / wrong answer. instead, you should keep your options open at each step, not blindly making the biggest leap towards the target. consider `decompose 99 [50,3]`.

Comment: (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm). --- another example is `decompose 18 [10, 6, 1] = 10 + 6 + 2*1 = 3*6` (in case we seek the solution with the smallest total amount of bills)

Comment: @WillNess - The denominations are hard coded, the code is tested and it works as intended. `decompose 99`, for example, returns `[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0]`. The 1-2-5 system that many real world currencies use is explicitly designed such that a greedy algorithm always succeeds and is optimal.

Comment: all true, but harder problems are more interesting to solve. :)

Comment: @WillNess - Also, OP's code is also a greedy algorithm (in fact, it's really equivalent to mine, just more convoluted) and it also fails if you use a different set of denominations.

Comment: As a starter in the language (and paradigm) I can't even understand what this code do, neither how it does. Can someone please tell me the names of the syntax/operators used in this code? I identified just the where keyword, the function assignment and the div and rem operators

Comment: @NathanPB if you're interesting in the solution to the problem, ask new question. this question asks something about some specific operator in Haskell, using the code only as a backdrop. to your comment's question, are you telling us you wrote the code using `filter` but do not recognize what `:` is?